# How to setup CodeIgniter on Ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having trouble making my CodeIgniter project work in Ubuntu since I've developed it on Windows. My main problem is that I don't even see any error or warning that can help me determine what the problem is. As you can see it's just a blank screen. The environment that I've declared in the index.php file is development and I've also enabled display_errors by setting it to On.

[image]

PHP also seems to be working fine since calling php_info() displays something. I believe I've also configured mysql properly. I've also declared the defaults(host, user, password, port) in php.ini. Can you give me any ideas on how to make something show up?Or something that would allow me to check if I've configured things properly. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Do you see anything in your error logs? Turn on `display_errors` and you might see errors in the browser.  It is best during development.

Comment: yes I already did that, but nothing is displaying.

Comment: I've had this problem before whereby I had named a class file incorrectly and the case sensitivity of the Unix system meant it couldn't find or load the file. For whatever reason I experienced the same issue- no errors logged

Comment: have you tried a clean installation of Codeigniter - to make sure it actually works in the first place ok?

Comment: @Laurencei: yes I got a clean installation working. I see the Welcome to code igniter page. Would it work if I copy those files to this clean install?

Comment: finally I'm making progress, I didn't autoload the database class it seems like there's something wrong with my database config but I don't know what it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're like me and you have installed Apache, PHP, and MySQL separately using `sudo apt-get`
then you most likely encounter the same error wherein there is nothing showing up in the logs and on the browser even if you have already `set display_errors to on`. 
What I did was to disable the autoloaded libraries one by one starting from the left.
And my problem was on the database class. Turns out that mysqli and mysql drivers for php isn't automatically installed when you install php.
All you have to do is to enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```

Doesn't matter if you have already installed php.

A little help from CodeIgniter could have save me a few hours trying to debug it.

Comment: Dont forget to accept your answer so that your question doesn't appear in unanswered lists anymore.

Comment: I had the same problem. No errors appearing anywhere.. just nothing turning up on the browser. Running Ubuntu and as soon as I did apt-get install php5-mysql it ran the post install scripts and seems to have fixed whatever was borked in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem shifting from Windows to Linux development is the naming. Linux distributions are strictly case sensitive regarding almost everything, unlike windows which allows the file indexing, regardless of the case.

First of all to show up something. On the first line of the document `index.php`

```
die("Showing Something");
```

If the message is being displayed, then remove the previous line and add a snippet to show up the errors

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: I've narrowed down the problem to the database. When I do not autoload the database class something shows up so the problem is on the database config. The database information I included in database.php is correct since it matches the information I used when logging into the client like heidi sql.

Comment: @user225269, Have you got any error messages? After implementing my solution.

Comment: there's none. Is there any way I could make use of the database class without autoloading it from the autoloads.php file?I really think its the root problem.

Comment: thanks for your help, I finally figured it out. It's the driver that I'm using, mysqli and mysql doesn't install by default in Ubuntu, you have to install them separately.

Comment: @user225269, Wow, Glad you solved that. Why dont you write a answer to your question?